# Angular/NgRx - effect: Cancel subscription and polling when angular expansion panel is closed

Tags: angular, ngrx, polling, effect

I have a list and each item/job is displayed in an angular material expansor panel.

When a user opens one of the expansors, I do a call to the API and get info to be displayed in the body of the expansor. There is also a pooling mechanism refreshing the data from the API every minute.

I need to start the subscription, do the http-call and start the polling, only for open expansors and cancel subscription and stop polling when the user closes any expansor

In the component - angular material expansor panel:

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.panelOpenState === true) {
      this.currentStatus$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromJobs.getcurrentRunStatus(this.jobIDSelected)));   
    }
    if (this.panelOpenState === false) {
      this.store.dispatch(new Cancel_Refresh_Execution_Statuses(this.jobIDSelected));
    }
  }
```

My issue is in the effect, when adding the param to dispacht the action only for a JOB_ID, when the expansor panel closes for this item/job, it gives me an error: 'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.'

This is my cancelling action:

```
export class Cancel_Refresh_Execution_Statuses implements Action {
  readonly type = JobsActionType.CANCEL_REFRESH_EXECUTION_STATUSES;
  constructor(public jobId: string) {}
}
```

```
  @Effect()
  refreshCurrentExecutedJobStatuses$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<jobActions.LoadJobStatusExecuted>(jobActions.JobsActionType.LOAD_JOB_STATUS_EXECUTED),
    mergeMap(
      (actions: jobActions.LoadJobStatusExecuted) =>
        timer(1000, 60000).pipe(
          concatMap(() =>
            from(
              this.jobsService.fetchJobsRunningStatus$(actions.param).pipe(
                takeUntil(
                  this.actions$.pipe(
                    ofType<jobActions.Cancel_Refresh_Execution_Statuses>(
                      //GETTING AN ERROR HERE: I CAN'T ADD A PARAM WITH THE JOB_ID 
                      //THAT I NEED TO CANCEL THE POLLING AND SUBSCRIPTION
                      jobActions.JobsActionType.CANCEL_REFRESH_EXECUTION_STATUSES(actions.param)
                    )
                  )
                ),
                map((lastRefreshStatus: Status) => new jobActions.JobsStatusExecutedSuccess(lastRefreshStatus)),
                catchError(err => of(new jobActions.JobsStatusExecutedFail(err)))
              )
            )
          )
        ) //end timer
    )
  );
```

Many thanks!

Comment: When close action panel is called, just use unsubscribe()

Answer (score 0):

ofType filters the action stream and has a type as parameter, not a function.

```
this.actions$.pipe(ofType(jobActions.JobsActionType.CANCEL_REFRESH_EXECUTION_STATUSES))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution working is setting the polling and the subscription/unsubscription in the component that displays the view:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new refreshJobLastStatus(this.jobId));
  this.currentStatus$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromJobs.refreshLastStatus(this.jobId)));
}

ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.panelOpenState) { 
    this.currentStatus$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromJobs.refreshLastStatus(this.jobId)));//here
    const timerRefreshJobStatuses = this.runtimeConfig.appConfig.jobsPollingRefreshStatus || 60000;
    this.statusesSub = timer(1000, timerRefreshJobStatuses).subscribe(() =>
      this.store.dispatch(new refreshJobLastStatus(this.jobId))
    );
     this.currentStatus$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromJobs.refreshLastStatus(this.jobId)));//?
  if (this.panelOpenState !== true) {
    if (this.statusesSub) {
      this.statusesSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  } 
}
```